# adding extension to chrome using chromeoptions doesnot work in selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, plugins, automation

I am a have a chrome extension developed, which I would like to have added to chrome.

When loaded the extension using the below code in selenium

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    String CurrentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String pluginDir = CurrentDir + "\\src\\main\\resources\\extensions\\newPlugin\\Chrome\\";
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--load-extension=", pluginDir);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Is there something I am missing? Please let me know

Comment: Check that the path actually exists. For instance, is `newPluin` directory name intentional?..

Comment: @alecxe Yes it is a valid directory name. I validated it by printing the directory name. Do we need to pass the chromeOptions to capabilities??